# Default to Area Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-areas

For an ASP.NET MVC application, I have 2 controllers with the name `Home`. One of the controllers is in an `Areas` section, one is not. If someone goes to the base path `/`, I am trying to default to the controller in the `Areas` section. I am under the impression that this is possible. I have the following setup which I believe is supposed to make that happen -

[image]

When I go to `/`, I am still taken to the Controller in `MVCArea01/Controllers/` and not `MVCArea01/Areas/Admin/Controllers/`.

(in case the code in the image is too small to see, here is the code for the method, RegisterRoutes)

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
        new[] {"MVCAreas01.Areas.Admin.Controllers"}  // I believe this code should cause "/" to go to the Areas section by default
    );

}
```

What is the correct solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ABogus

I modified the AdminAreaRegistration.cs file. Refer the image below

[image: Modified the MapRoute]

Also I modified the Route.config as below.

[image: Route.config is also modified.]

I got the output as like this

[image: Default route to Areas->Admin->Controller->Home]

You can download the sample project from https://www.dropbox.com/s/o8in2389e8aebak/SOMVC.zip

Comment: Thanks for the try, VeeKayBee. But this did not work. This appears to be a tough one to figure out.

Comment: @ABogus Sorry for the late response. Please check the updated answer and let me know your next challenge :)

Comment: That worked, VeeKayBee! Except... I made my change in the Global.ascx.cs file instead of RouteConfig.cs because I don't have a RouteConfig.cs. What's up with that?

Comment: No Probs. I think you are using MVC3. In my case its MVC4. Routeconfig.cs contains a function which adds all route. In MVC4 they just separated the function which add route to another class. The function call is from Global.asax only. They did a simple abstraction. Thanks @ABogus for your response.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { 
            controller = "Home", 
            action = "Index", 
            id = UrlParameter.Optional, 
            area = "Admin" 
       }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer flem, but I am still getting an error - "Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'Home'. This can happen if the route that services this request ('{controller}/{action}/{id}') does not specify namespaces to search for a controller that matches the request. If this is the case, register this route by calling an overload of the 'MapRoute' method that takes a 'namespaces' parameter.

The request for 'Home' has found the following matching controllers:
MVCAreas01.Areas.Admin.Controllers.HomeController
MVCAreas01.Controllers.HomeController"

Comment: Try including your fourth parameter.

Comment: I tried adding the 4th parameter, but the HomeController in the Area is NOT being called, the other HomeController is being called.

Answer (score 0):

You should create additional route for your starting page, that will direct processing to the right controller:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Home_Default",
        "",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        new[] { "MVCAreas01.Areas.Admin.Controllers" });

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        namespaces: new[] { "MVCAreas01.Controllers" }
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for attempting, Adas. But this did not work. That's 3 attempts by people trying to answer this and 3 strikes! It still took me to the HomeController that is NOT in the Areas/Admin section.